# How do I correctly add the HyperlinkedRelatedField field to the serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to make it possible for a json that gives all the model instances to go to a particular instance using the additional url field in the serializer.
There is a view to display the list

```
class DocumentsListView(viewsets.ViewSetMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True,)
    queryset = Documents.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DocumentsSerializer
    permission_classes = []

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

**urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('', DocumentsListView)

urlpatterns = [
    url('', include(router.urls), name='files')
]
```

**serializers.py**

```
class DocumentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='documents-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Documents
        fields = ('id',  'filename', 'datafile', 'type', 'created', 'url')
```

but got an error

```
 'Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, '
AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.
```

If I set `read_only='True'`, it works, but url didnt displayed

I've also tried this way of implementing serializer

```
class DocumentsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Documents
        fields = ('id',  'filename', 'datafile', 'type', 'created', 'url')
```

but got an error

```
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "doctype-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field
```

Answer (score 0):

Recall that every view has a serializer set in serializer_class, and your serializer has a Meta class where you set a model, and thats how you reference the model type you're relating to in `HyperLinkedRelatedField`. The view_name field is the name of that model followed by '-list' if the url you request does not end with an id(for example when making POST requests), and '-detail' if it does.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I added to `view_name`  values `documents-detail`. But got error, I changed question

Comment: print `router.urls` and tell us the output, it will give you the name of your view

Comment: Did you do this in urls.py?

Comment: I got `[<RegexURLPattern documents-list ^$>, <RegexURLPattern documents-list ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>, <RegexURLPattern documents-detail ^(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$>, <RegexURLPattern documents-detail ^(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>, <RegexURLPattern api-root ^$>, <RegexURLPattern api-root ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>]
`

Comment: Error is the same

Comment: Have you tried overriding get_queryset in your viewset?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you eventually solved it but I also experienced something similar, and the solution was changing the HyperlinkedRelatedField to an HyperlinkedIdentityField.